# a matrix-valued function $A(x)$ is continuous iff each of its entries $a_{ij}(x)$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, proof-verification

This is basically an extension question of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, p211.

Specifically, suppose $A(x)$ is a mapping from some metric space $X$ into $M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$, i.e. the set of $m$-by-$n$ (real) matrices.  The book (p211) states that $A(x)$ is continuous on $X$ if each entry $a_{ij}(x)$ of $A(x)$ is continuous on $X$.  (For $A,B\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$, we define $\Vert A\Vert \triangleq \underset{\Vert u\Vert\le 1, u\in \mathbb R^n}\max \Vert Au\Vert_2$, and distance $d(A,B)\triangleq \Vert A-B\Vert$.)

But it appears to me that the converse is also true.  I'd appreciate it if someone can confirm or refute it for me.  Here's my justification:  Suppose $A(x)$ is continuous on $X$.  Then 
$$|a_{ij}(x)-a_{ij}(y)|=\Big |v_i^T[A(x)-A(y)]e_j\Big |\le \Big\Vert [A(x)-A(y)]e_j\Big \Vert_2\le \Big\Vert A(x)-A(y)\Big \Vert,$$
where $v_i, e_j$ are standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n$ respectively.  So $|a_{ij}(x)-a_{ij}(y)|\to 0$, as $x\to y$, the desired conclusion.  Am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: You are correct. A more abstract way to say this is that the functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by each coordinate are continuous. The conclusion is that the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by the Euclidean norm is the same as the product topology.

Comment: (Sorry, above substitute the space of matrices and the operator norm as appropriate.)